# How to open a link in new tab when I click on link in an email.?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

**The use case**

I run windows 7 and internet explorer 11 is my default browser.

Every time I click on a link in an email (or any other software), a new instance of internet explorer starts.

I end with dozens of IE instances opened after some hours.

**Question**

Is it possible to change a windows or browser setting that forces any link to open into an existing IE/Chrome/Firefox instance (as a tab) instead of a new browser instance?

- **Please, I am not interested by answers such as:** change the browser setting and enable the 'open new link in new tabs' :-)
- This is not a programmatic issue, don't propose javascript solutions

Thank you for you help

Comment: No way. It's browser settings -- to open new window ( window.open / target="_blank" )  in new Tab or in new Instance

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk OK, let other answer then I can close the issue